# Why can't I access properties of my custom cell?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have created a custom cell for my tableView that looks like this:

[image]

In `cellForRowAt` I load the `cell` like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "ColleagueViewId")
    let nib: NSArray = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ColleagueViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)! as NSArray
    cell = nib[0] as! ColleagueViewCell

    //Doesn't work:
    cell.nameOfObj
    cell.imButton

    return cell

}
```

But I can't access the properties of the custom `cell`. If I run the app, I do get the custom `cell` but without the data (since I haven't added it yet). The `cell` class is written in `objective c` and the `h` file is in the bridge. Like I said, I get the `cell` and it's shown with the proper layout. So why can't I get a hold of the properties? Let me know if you would like me to show additional code or something else.

***EDIT*** 
Here's my `cell` class `ColleagueViewCell`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class InternalContact;

@interface ColleagueViewCell : UITableViewCell {
    IBOutlet UILabel *__weak nameCall;
    IBOutlet UILabel *__weak forwardCall;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *__weak iconImageView;
    IBOutlet UIButton *__weak imButton;

    InternalContact *contact;
}

@property(strong) InternalContact *contact;

@property (nonatomic, weak) UILabel *nameCall;
@property (nonatomic, weak) UILabel *forwardCall;
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIImageView *iconImageView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIButton *imButton;

@end
```

Comment: Please show your code in `ColleagueViewCell`

Comment: have you declared those nameOfObj and imButton in ColleagueViewCell ? can you show ColleagueViewCell code ?

Comment: Why aren't you dequeuing the cell? Is there any specific reason to load it using loadNibNamed?

Comment: I added the code for `ColleagueViewCell`. As for why I don't deque my cell instead, it crashes for some reason, but doesn't crash with `reuseIdentifier`. Perhaps that could be the issue? The crash says that it's nil with this: `var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ColleagueViewId", for: indexPath) as! ColleagueViewCell`

Comment: @PGDev Ok, PGDev, you were right! First I registered the cell like this:         `tableView.register(ColleagueViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")` then I dequed it like this: `var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ColleagueViewCell`. Now I can access all properties! Thanks :) Write a real answer if you want me to check it and upvote it :)

Comment: Great. I've added the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of loading the cell using `loadNibName(_:owner:options:`), you must dequeue the `cell` using the `reuseIdentifier` using `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)`.

So, replace the below code,

```
var cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "ColleagueViewId")
let nib: NSArray = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ColleagueViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)! as NSArray
cell = nib[0] as! ColleagueViewCell
```

with

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ColleagueViewCell
```

Before that you must register `ColleagueViewCell` with the `tableView` using,

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ColleagueViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```